# Compile error: type mismatch

Tags: types, mismatch

I get a Compile error:Type mismatch with the below code. Not sure if the issue is in the code. Please help and thanks in advance.

Public Sub TransferTest()

```
Dim FiWkb As Workbook
Dim BkWkb As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set FiWkb = "C:\Users\60050987\Desktop\FI INSPECTOR PROJECT\FI Inspector Data.xlsx"
Set BkWkb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\60050987\Desktop\FI INSPECTOR PROJECT\FI Inspector Data.xlsx")

'Now, transfer values from x to y:
BkWkb.Sheets("PhosData").Range("A2").Value = FiWkb.Sheets("DaysReport").Range("A2")

'Close BkWkb:
BkWkb.Close
```

End Sub

Comment: Which line is the mismatch, with the transfer line?  If so, could you simply be missing the `.Value` portion on the right-hand side? It's been awhile since I've used VBA, so I could be wrong ... Unless you meant to copy one range to another, without the `.Value` on the left-hand side? Unfortunately, I have no way to test VBA at the moment.

Comment: I fixed the issue. Instead of trying to assign the variable FiWkb I simply referred to it as ThisWorkbook since that is the workbook the code is being executed in.